# how to do css changes only to links that are in side specific div without defining classes to a elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to add some css changes only to  the a(link) elements, that are placed inside divs whose class names are defined as "x". (not to all links in the page)
is there any proper way to do that other than defining classes to each and every "a" elements.

```
<body>
<div class="x"> <a>Home</a></div> <!--to these-->
<div class="x"> <a>contact</a></div><!--to these-->
<div class="x"> <a>about</a></div><!--to these-->
<a>hello</a><!--but not this-->
</body>
```

if what i'm asking is not clear
consider: i want to change the decoration of a that is placed in side a div,and i can do it like this

```
.x.m{text-decoration:none;}
<div class="x"><a class="m"></a></div>
```

but i want to know if there are any other methods to do the same without defining a class to element "a".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this like

```
.x a {text-decoration:none;}
```

here is the example [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e86mpdhw/2/)